# Using Magento 1.4's WYSIWYG editor on custom admin pages

Tags: magento, tinymce

Anyone know how to get the new 1.4 WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) working with custom admin pages?

I have some modules I made that have input fields in the admin->system->config section, and I’d like to get the new editor to show on the textareas there, but I can't find where they are defined.

Answer (score 6):

To load the TINY MCE on a specific page,  use the following function on the Adminhtml Edit block of your module:

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
 parent::_prepareLayout();
 if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
 }
}
```

To enable the editor for a certain editable textfield, just use 'wysiwyg'   => true, instead of 'wysiwyg'   => false. i.e.:

```
$fieldset->addField('description', 'editor', array(
    'name'      => 'description',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('sevents')->__('Description'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('sevents')->__('Description'),
    'style'     => 'height:12em;width:500px;',
    'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
    'wysiwyg'   => true,
    'required'  => true,
));
```

Comment: Thanks for this Arion - this has gotten me a little closer - I've overridden **Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php** adding the first section of code above, so I now have the tinymce setup js files loading, as can be seen in my page head. However, my custom modules have their input fields specified through the system.xml file, in **app/code/community/MyName/MyModuleName/etc**, not as per your second block of code. Is there someway to specify, in this file, to load the wysiwyg editor for a particular field?

Comment: I looked for this for a quite a while. By overriding the _prepareLayout method per Arion's instructions, wysiwyg is enabled for my module's edit blocks. Thanks!

Comment: I did what arion said but i get the following error in firebug tinyMCE is not defined

Comment: if you need to add it in a tab you may need to look into this file:core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Content.php ...      `$form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');`

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few simple steps that will help you make TinyMCE work with Magento CMS pages.

### Step 1.

[Download](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php) and unpack TinyMCE to root /js folder. Two things to keep in mind here. Download regular version (not jQuery version) of TinyMCE. This is due to the fact that Magento uses Prototype, so we need to avoid conflicts. Second, watch out for unpack location. Your tiny_mce.js file should be accessible on `js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js` path.

### Step 2.

Open the `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Main.php` file. Locate the

```
 $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
        'name'      => 'content',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Content'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Content'),
        'style'     => 'height:36em;',
        'wysiwyg'   => false,
        'required'  => true,
    ));
```

and change it to

```
 $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
        'name'      => 'content',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Content'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Content'),
        'style'     => 'height:36em;',
        'wysiwyg'   => true,
        'theme' => 'advanced',
        'required'  => true,
    ));
```

As you can see, here we changed on existing attribute ("wysiwyg") value and added new attribute "theme".

### Step 3.

Open the `/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Editor.php` file and locate the method getElementHtml(). Here we change

```
 $html = '
    <textarea name="'.$this->getName().'" title="'.$this->getTitle().'" id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'" class="textarea '.$this->getClass().'" '.$this->serialize($this->getHtmlAttributes()).' >'.$this->getEscapedValue().'</textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
            /* tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "exact",
                theme : "'.$this->getTheme().'",
                elements : "' . $element . '",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
                extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
                theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : "false",
                theme_advanced_resizing : "false",
                apply_source_formatting : "true",
                convert_urls : "false",
                force_br_newlines : "true",
                doctype : \'< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\'
            });*/
        //]]>
    </script>';
```

to

```
 $html = '
    <textarea name="'.$this->getName().'" title="'.$this->getTitle().'" id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'" class="textarea '.$this->getClass().'" '.$this->serialize($this->getHtmlAttributes()).' >'.$this->getEscapedValue().'</textarea>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
        Event.observe(window, "load", function() {
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "exact",
                theme : "'.$this->getTheme().'",
                elements : "' . $element . '",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
                extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
                theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : "false",
                theme_advanced_resizing : "false",
                apply_source_formatting : "true",
                convert_urls : "false",
                force_br_newlines : "true",
                doctype : \'< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\'
            });
        });
    //]]>
    </script>';
```

As you can see, there were only three minor changes needed (download, modify, modify) to get the TinyMCE editor working.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

© Branko Ajzele ([source](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-make-tinymce-work-with-magento-cms-pages/))

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately it's not quite what I needed. I already made my own TinyMCE extension for Magento before, for version 1.3, but since they added it into the new 1.4 version, I want to find out how to use that default TinyMCE package to show the editor on my own custom extensions. I don't see the point of having two separate versions of TinyMCE when surely one can manage to do everything, if I can just find which file specifies the text areas to be used with it.

Comment: I have double-checked, WYSIWYG for content pages works right after installation of v.1.4.0.1

Describe your case in more detail, perhaps it's all about your database. Here's a post that might help: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/77777/

Comment: It works for the standard content pages (CMS page & blocks) but not for custom extensions. I have some custom extensions I made that have text areas as inputs in the admin->system->configuration section (like I stated originally), and they aren't affected by the default WYSIWYG editor. So what I'm asking is, which file, in the Magento core, specifies the text areas that should have the editor added to them.

Comment: There is no such file, all you need to do is create your text areas with the following code: `$fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array( 'wysiwyg'   => true ... ) ) ;` Or you may optionally create TinyMCE manually, passing `elements : "my_textarea_id"` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks again, but my text area input fields are created via my extension's system.xml file, not through the database, so I can't see any way to add this in. From my own searches through the core files, it seems that it can only be enabled for CMS pages:
     if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);}

Guess I'll just have to use my own one as well as the default.

Answer (score 1):

in EW_Press_Block_Adminhtml_Press_Edit
(EW/Press/Block/Adminhtml/Press/Edit.php)
paste this function

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled())
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
    }
}
```

and than in the form.php (EW_Press_Block_Adminhtml_Press_Edit_Tab_Form)
/*(EW/Press/Block/Adminhtml/Press/Edit/Tab/Form.php)*/

'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),

add it so it will look like below:

```
$fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
          'name'      => 'content',
          'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Site Description'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Site Description'),
          'style'     => 'width:400px; height:300px;',
          'required'  => true,
          'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
          'wysiwyg'   => true
      ));
```

now reload the page to see the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that I followed.

**Preparing editor used in edit form** 
app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule/Edit.php

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    // added this code 
    if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
    }
    parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

**Transforming textarea to editor**

app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule/Edit/Tab/Form.php

Include the content within ‘_prepareForm()‘ function

```
$config = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(
array(
'add_widgets' => false,
'add_variables' => false,
'add_images' => false,
'files_browser_window_url'=> $this->getBaseUrl().'admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/',
));



$fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
'name' => 'content',
'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Content'),
'title' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__(’Content'),
'style’ => 'width:700px; height:320px;',
'wysiwyg' => true,
'required' => true,
'config' => $config,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above post i have written an article entitled:
 
[How to use WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) in custom Admin Magento Module](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-use-wysiwyg-editor-tinymce-in-custom-admin-magento-module/)

Hope this helps.